# Casting type in generic method

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I need to make this class as generic as possible... I want to pass a XML string Path and return the data of the type of object I pass to the getDataFromFile() Method.
Here's what I made so far:

```
public class XmlFile
{
    public string mXmlFilePath { get; set; }

    public XmlFile(string xmlFilePath)
    {
        this.mXmlFilePath = xmlFilePath;
    }

    public object getDataFromFile(object dataObject)
    {
        LogFile.addLogEntry("Getting data from XML file.");

        object data = null;
        Type type = dataObject.GetType();

        try
        {

            StreamReader xmlStream = new StreamReader(this.mXmlFilePath);
            XmlSerializer xmlfile = new XmlSerializer(type);
            data = (type)xmlfile.Deserialize(xmlStream);
            xmlStream.Close();
            return data;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogFile.addLogEntry("Error reading data from XML file: " + ex.Message);
            return null;
        }         
    }
}
```

I know I should be using reflection, but I'm having trouble making this cast `data = (type)xmlfile.Deserialize(xmlStream);`

thank you...

Comment: That does not make sence at all? The method returns still a `object` if you cast or not. And the method is not generic. What you want to archive?

Comment: You should use generics https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
public T getDataFromFile<T>()
{
    LogFile.addLogEntry("Getting data from XML file.");
    try
    {
        using(StreamReader xmlStream = new StreamReader(this.mXmlFilePath))
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlfile = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)xmlfile.Deserialize(xmlStream);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogFile.addLogEntry("Error reading data from XML file: " + ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mario.This is exacly what I need. Obrigado!